# Acknowledgement, retransmission of layer2 is actually belongs to layer4?

Tags: ip-address, layer2, layer3, transport-protocol, layer4

I followed from this [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77809/osi-model-with-respect-to-data-packet-lost-corrupted/77810?noredirect=1#comment140545_77810) understand that only transport layer responsible for acknowledgement. But I have read on book stop and wait, GBN, SR protocols  uses acknowledgement, retransmission in DLL.

My question is they(acknowledgement, retransmission in DLL) are actually layer4 acknowledgement which passes through layer2?

Comment: do you understand the difference between a layer and a protocol?

Comment: @Effie yes, I understand.

Comment: "only transport layer responsible for acknowledgement" this is again the opposite of what I said

Comment: GBN, SR, and etc are mechanisms, that can be employed by a protocol. A protocol can work on any layer.

Comment: @Effie by default layer 4 is responsible for acknowledgement. You said if I implement reliable layer2 for layer4 then there will be many problem.you said ""in order for link layer to interpret layer 4 acks, link layer had to be able to interpret layer 4 (and layer 3 for the matter). this kinda negates the point of having layers to separate these things in the first place"""

Comment: OSI model is designed to describe networks in general, not Internet in particualar. You can design a network with reliable layer 3. Internet is just not one of those.

Comment: if you wifi access point is interpreting TCP, than this particular feature is not layer 2 function.

Comment: @Effie co mean?

Comment: every protocol that provides ACKs and retransmissions has its own ACKs and its own retransmissions. it is not inspecting upper layer protocols to do so.

Comment: layer 4 acks are just packets from the point of view of layer 2. (if it is a packet switched network of course)

Comment: @Effie accumulated above comments make it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Effie  in previous answer statement "In practice, it is not quite this simple. TCP performance on networks with losses is quite suboptimal (mostly due to reasons that have something to do with congestion control). This is why wireless is usually reliable. "---please elaborate what do u mean? What do u mean when losses in layer4 then wireless is reliable? Please reply.

Comment: i need to look for references, and i can't do this right now.

Comment: @Effie explain above comments little bit.

Comment: wireless APs do some optimizations to improve tcp performance. these require inspecting tcp headers. this is however not a layer 2 functionality that fits into OSI model.

Comment: i don't remember now what exactly that is. I know that there were several research papers that proposed stuff. I don't know which one is actually done.

Comment: @Effie "wireless APs do some optimizations to improve tcp performance. these require inspecting tcp headers "--- wifi inspect tcp headers in layer2?

Comment: wifi does not inspect the header. wireless AP (router) can do this, and this is not layer 2 functionality.

Comment: you can forget i said this for now. you need to understand the theory first. in theory this should not happen.

Comment: @Effie wireless AP (router) inspect tcp headers in layer2?

Comment: @Effie wireless AP (router) inspect tcp headers in layer2 or layer3?

Comment: A network device, e.g., wireless AP, is not a purely layer 2 device. It can have functionality of many layers. It can also have other functions: firewall, nat box, etc . I don't know how these functions fit into OSI model. Optimizing TCP performance is one of those. It is neither layer 2 nor layer 3, probably layer 4.

Comment: @Effie please accumated above comments make it as answer, which will be summary for me.

Comment: @Effie I don't understand one thing to optimize layer4 we need to make  layer2  reliable, my question is why we need insect tcp header? It's not understand.

Comment: give me a couple of days, i will try to find the references. it is actually not that obvious.

Comment: wifi being reliable is not because of tcp. wifi is reliable because wireless medium is error prone. Usually if someone sends the packet, it wants the packet to be delivered.  It makes not a lot of sense to have an error prone medium at the last hop that incure high packet loss. If wifi was not reliable, then either the packets need to be retransmitted from the source and travel all the way back and potentially get lost again (e.g., TCP), or the end-system has to deal with missing packets (e.g., multimedia). It makes more sense to have a reliable layer 2.

Comment: also retransmissions between two layer 2 neighbors on a wireless network occur much faster (you have a pretty small propagation delay, then you can have a much smaller retransmission timer).

Comment: @Effie could I say layer2 ARQ and layer2 reliable both are same?

Comment: hm... not exaclty, ARQ is a mechanism that can be used to achieve reliablility. Reliability means that the layer providing certain guarantees about packet/frame delivery to the upper layer. It says nothing about how. ARQ is a set of mechanisms that can be used by a protocol of certain layer to achieve this, if the lower layer is unreliable.

Comment: if you manage to design a protocol that achieves certain guarantees without acknowledgements or retransmissions, you can call it reliable, but not use ARQ. You can also use ARQ and be unreliable. E.g., you can attempt to transmit each packet 3 times, if it fails, then move to the next anyways. then you employ an ARQ, but do not provide reliable service.

Comment: @Effie you are saying ARQ is used to achieve reliability, to achieve reliability use set of mechanism. Both are same by transitive property.

Comment: this is why I say "not exactly". these are two different concepts. they are very closely related, but they are very subtly different.

Comment: let's put it like this. physical layer is always unreliable, because it is physically impossible not to have physical errors in a signal.  So, there is always an unreliable layer in the network. Then you stack layers on top of it, and at some point some layer will probably want to provide reliable delivery. And AFAIK there are no mechanism available that does not use ARQ.

Comment: you can include protection against certain number of errors - you can check error-correcting codes (layer 1) and forward error correction (this can be used at any layer). but if you need to hanle most of the errors, you will still need ARQ. (again AFAIK)

Comment: actually, i can probably rephrase this in terms of object-oriented programming. reliable/unreliable describe the interface. ARQ describes implementation detail.

Comment: @Effie one thing tell : I have read on book regarding SR mechanism in data link lyer, out of order delivery is possible(where GBN only accepts in-order delivery), then sorting operation happen in receiver side in DLL. My question is if everything is happen in either sender or receiver then network layer or transport layer always got in-order delivery?

Comment: hm, it is hard to answer this question in general. if there is more than one hop (like you picture in the other question), then DLL SR only guarantee in-order delivery on a single hop. there is nothing preventing packets to be delivered out of order somewhere else along the path. if there is only one hop, then it is hard to say. i would say that network layer gets packets in-order. However, for transport layer there is no guarantee, because layer 3 is not required to provide guarantees and layer 3 can still do something to reorder the packets

Comment: i guess IP can reorder packets if they are fragmented and it does IP reassembly

Comment: @Effie if layer2 send into layer3 in-order, so why layer3 further doing reordering? If I agree layer3 doing further reordering, but layer4 why not get reordered packets?

Comment: you can't view it like this. layer 3 is not necessarily "doing" reordering. It is permitted to do so. That is a network device is not violating specification if some packets are reordered. It doesn't imply that the device should do it. It implies, that nothing should break if it does.

Comment: you have to design a network, which can actually be built, i.e., you have to actually have hardware that can work. Internet is composed of a lot of small networks, under different administrative domains, with different layer 2s, different cables/wireless, different speeds, etc. Enabling such heterogeneity was intended by design. When you have such design, you should think, where is the best place to handle certain errors, like reordering. And doing it in transport layer on end-systems is easier than in network layer.

Comment: @Effie "However, for transport layer there is no guarantee, because layer 3 is not required to provide guarantees and layer 3 can still do something to reorder the packets"--- I don't understand this statement. Why there is no gurantee transport layer get in- order, but network layer get in-order?

Comment: i don't understand, sorry

Comment: IP is supposed to work on top of a very large number of imaginable and unimaginable layer 2 protocols. This is why it was desgined to provide very few guarantees. Transport layer works on top of IP, so it has to work on the guarantees IP provides. If there is a specific combination of layer 2 on the path, that provides much more guarantees, then some stuff won't happen. You still have to have transport layer be prepared for all the stuff, because otherwise it won't work on all supported networks.

Comment: @Effie your are right. But my question is suppose one router is between sender and receiver, and router DLL using SR mechanism then receiver DLL,network layer,transport layer will get always in-order packet. In this scenario reordering isn't need for transport layer? Am I correct?

Comment: in this case you have reliable delivery sender <-> router and reliable delivery router <-> receiver. this is not end-to-end reliable delivery. it is possible that the router receives packets, then for some reason reorders them, and then sends reordered packets to the receiver. if the router would do this, then the transport layer can receive reordered packets. Now, I personally, cannot think of any good reason for a router to actually do this, so I would assume that this usually won't happen. But again, it is allowed behavior and you cannot build transport layer that cannot deal with reorders.

Comment: (for the record - the router is also permitted to drop packets and duplicate packets. dunno why would duplicating happen, but dropping packets is a pretty common scenario)

Comment: @Effie one thing tell when layer2 received the packet from layer3, then layer2 could understand/recognize that inside data layer3,layer4 contents (up address,port no. etc) are present?

Comment: in theory layer2 should not do this. layer2 header should have a header field that points to layer 3 protocol in use (e.g., ethertype), so layer 2 can pass the packet to the correct layer 3. otherwise in theory layer2 should not interpret packets. in practice you can have a network device interpret upper layers as performance optimization or something similar, but i don't know how this fits into OSI model. I would start with learning "in theory" first

Comment: @Effie fragmentation by any layer2 protocol is possible?

Comment: hm, that I don't know, ask someone more experienced

Comment: @Effie I see till now when one computer connected to one switch port, so that interface and computer uses same Mac address. Two router interface connected via one link then both interface uses the same/one mac address?

Comment: ehm, i don't think there is any situation where two systems on the same "link" use the same mac address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are layers, there are protocols, and there are mechanisms.

GBN, SR, etc are examples of mechanisms. These can be implemented by a protocol to achieve reliability. There are different protocols that use different mechanisms.

Protocols usually are assigned to layers. There are layer 2, layer 3, and layer 4 protocols.

Each of the layers can employ a protocol that uses mechanisms such as acknowledgements and retransmissions. Protocols on different layers are (in theory) independent of each other. Actually, protocols are usually just independent of each other, unless they are specifically designed to work together and together only. If several protocols use acknowledgements, these acknowledgements are independent of each other. Layer 2 will  employ a layer 2 protocol that has its own acknowledgments. These acknowledgments are completely independent of any other acknowledgements of any other protocols that any other layer may or may not use. For layer 2, TCP acks are just packets, nothing special. They only have meaning for the TCP instance on the other side.

> I followed from this question understand that only transport layer responsible for acknowledgement.

No. First, OSI model is designed to reason about networks in general, not Internet in particular. A network can have reliable protocols on any layer, including layer 3.

Internet is a particular network, where layer 3 is not reliable, and does not use any mechanism. In Internet, reliable **end-to-end** delivery needs to be achieved by layer 4 or above. This is because layer 3 does not provide any guarantees even if a specific layer 2 does.

Layer 2 can provide relible delivery between two layer 2 hops. This is reliable delivery on a single layer 2 hop, not end-to-end. The packet can still be lost on any other hop along the way. This is why we need a separate mechanism fo reliable end-to-end delivery.

Comment: I learned so many critical concepts only because of you. Thank you.

Comment: if I using layer2 reliable(wifi) and udp for layer4 then it will be valid design?

Comment: *Internet is a particular network,*  I think you mean the *TCP/IP protocol suite,.*

Comment: @RonTrunk yes, it's possible?

Comment: @AlokMaity  I don't know what you mean by *valid design*.  But as an example, think about using DNS on your wireless network.

Comment: @RonTrunk I mean if I make reliable layer2 and use udp for layer4 , but udp is connectionless, if I use layer2 reliable then will not take much time?

Comment: @AlokMaity  You can invent any protocol or combine protocols any way you like.  I'll say it again:  think about using DNS on your wireless network as an example of what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

> understand that only transport layer responsible for acknowledgement.

The transport layer is the layer where delivery is usually tracked (most prominently by TCP). Acknowledgments are sometimes also used on other layers, where delivery isn't very reliable (e.g. in IEEE 802.11's data link layer).

In theory, any protocol in any layer could implement some kind of data acknowledge mechanism. You should note that whatever protocol implements such a mechanism, it has no relation to other layers used. Ie. when TCP is transmitted (over IP) over 802.11, both 802.11 and TCP track delivery independently: 802.11 between wireless nodes, TCP from the source to the destination.

Comment: one thing tell : I have read on book regarding SR mechanism in data link lyer, out of order delivery is possible(where GBN only accepts in-order delivery), then sorting operation happen in receiver side in DLL. My question is if everything is happen in either sender or receiver then network layer or transport layer always got in-order delivery?

Comment: Out-of-order delivery is possible anywhere but resorting only ever happens on the transport layer, when the L4 protocol supports that. Out-of-order delivery is mostly due to multiple routing paths, where one path is faster than the other and later packets can overtake earlier packets. Also, lost and resent L4 segments may arrive later than segments that where sent later.

Comment: one thing tell when layer2 received the packet from layer3, then layer2 could understand/recognize that inside data layer3,layer4 contents (up address,port no. etc) are present?

Comment: No layer ever understands or cares about the higher-layer payload it transports. L1 doesn't understand L2 frames, L2 doesn't understand L3 packets, L3 doesn't understand L4 datagrams/segments, and so on. The point of layering network functionality is that each layer has a specific range of tasks, and no layer needs to understand what the others do.

Comment: fragmentation by any layer2 protocol is possible?

Comment: Not that I know of or could imagine, certainly not with Ethernet or 802.11.

Comment: two router interface connected via one link then both interface uses the same/one ip address?

Comment: IP addresses need to be unique, so no, that's not possible.

Comment: but two router  network id could be same?

Comment: You mean the subnet prefix? Yes, that must the same on a shared link.

Comment: I see till now when one computer connected to one switch port, so that interface and computer uses same Mac address. Two router interface connected via one link then both interface uses the same/one mac address?

Comment: No, MAC addresses need to also be unique, at least within the same network (L2 segment).